# Checking if a new value added to a dict is in between -1 and 1

Tags: python

I have a code block which checks if a value exists in a dict, if it does, I take its value, if it does not, I create a new key which is a parameter passed to a function from a list, the value of the new key is the user's input. I have to make sure that the input is in between `-1` and `1`, this all is done in `else` block:

`my_dict = {'a':10, 'b':20}`

if key is present in my_dict, just add 10+20, if 'c' is passed, it is not in 'my_dict', I create
a 'key' 'c' and the value is user's input from -1 to 1.

```
else: #when 'c' is passed
    my_dict[item] = float(input(f'write a number for {item} from -1 to 1'))
    while my_dict[item] > 1 and my_dict[item]<-1:
        my_dict[item] = float(input(f'write a number for  {item} from -1 to 1!!!'))
    sum+=my_dict[item]
```

But when the function meets a key which is not in `my_dict`, it asks to enter a value from the first input, it accepts any value, like -100 or 100 so the `while` condition is not checked.

I want to ask the user to enter another value for `my_dict[item]` as long as he does not enter a value between `-1` and `1`.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: `while my_dict[item] < 1 and my_dict[item]>-1:`?

Comment: Think carefully about the logic as you wrote it. What are the two things that need to be true for the `while` block to be entered? Can those both be true at the same time?

Comment: Got it, `while` will never be entered because a number cant be both: more than 1 and less than -1. Thats why I need `or`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm interpreting it correctly, you're asking to continue

```py
while my_dict[item] > 1 or my_dict[item] < -1:
```

This while loop will force the user to continue inputting new values as long as the values provided are not between 1 and -1.